# iPhone crashes Dlink DI-624 router regularly

Tags: iphone, router

I've got an iPhone4 running 4.01 that is connecting to a DLink DI-624. I'm getting intermittent connections. Sometimes these are resolved by rebooting the router, sometimes not. Sometimes rebooting the phone fixes it, sometimes not.

Do people have [similar problems](https://serverfault.com/questions/38724/mac-laptop-crashing-wireless-router) with Apple products? What solutions have you found?

Comment: Are you using WPA security?

Comment: I've had problems with D-Link routers on iOS 4.1. I never targeted the issue, but inevitably, my router needed to be reset once daily, or else all the devices/computers in my house wouldn't be able to connect to my WLAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the good Upgrade to iOS 4.1 suggestion, bear in mind that certain routers are less resilient than others to a lot of traffic or odd situations (double DHCP servers, ip conflicts, etc).

I’d make sure that the router has the latest firmware. A local device (a PC, a Phone, etc.) should **never** crash a router. If your internet connection is being affected, blame the router 1st.

Answer (score 1):

You should [upgrade to iOS 4.1](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/software-update/) as it has several bug fixes, maybe you are experiencing a know problem that has been fixed in the latest release.

All reports from the new **iOS 4.1** (made publicly available yesterday through iTunes Update), they always say it's much better, even on my iPhone 3G it's fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

While upgrading to newer iOS releases is not a bad idea, this is not going to solve your problem.

Over time, I discovered that there are many routers that are blocked or crashed by Apple devices. This is not Apple fault, it the bad router software and the *ONLY* solution is to upgrade the firmware or change it to an open-source alternative firmware.

Another alternative is to buy another router, preferably a better brand than Dlink. So far I prefer to pay double for a Cisco/Linksys router than loosing time due to a cheap one.

I tried cheap ones, and all I got was a lot of lost time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPA, a lot of routers of that era had incomplete and broken WPA implementations.  I had the same issue with an iPhone 3G back then.  I had to bin the router as it had no updated firmware.

Try switching to WEP or no encryption for a short time to see if that stops the disconnects.